# Extraer elementos contiguos iguales de una lista o array en python para referencia de uso en UiPath

Tags: python, algoritmos, uipath

Buenos tardes amigos:
Supongamos que tengamos esta lista

```
facturas = ['z', 'z', 'z', 'b', 'b', 'j', j', j', 'd', 'd']
```

Me gustaría saber tener un resultado final de la siguiente manera

```
  facturas_z = ['z', 'z', 'z']
  facturas_b = ['b', 'b']
  facturas_j = ['j', j', j']
  facturas_d= ['d', 'd']
```

El problema es que quizás podría usas un doble for/While, ya quiero usarlo como referencia en Uipath y el problema es el siguiente:

Hay un PDF con 80 o más paginas, los proveedores siempre vienen de manera contigua y para la solución estor utilizando el OCR para leer
el nombre del proveedor de cada pagina y compararla con la anterior.
Entonces no puedo recorrer todo la lista para compararlo con el primer elemento porque demoraría mucho (En Uipath).

Entonces me gustaría hacer una algoritmo que realice lo siguiente:

1. leer los dos primeros elementos
2. de estos dos elementos comparar el ultimo con el primero
3. Si esa comparación en correcta,
4. leer el tercer elemento y si es igual al primero continuar hasta encontrar un elemento diferente.
5. generar la primera lista de elementos iguales contiguos
6. Continuar con los siguientes elementos hasta finalizar

Agradezco de antemano toda comentario, Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido, es demasiado importante agregues lo que intentaste o investigaste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: 1. en Python no existen los array 2. que haz intentado? recuerda que te ayudaremos si vemos que tienes interés por aprender.

Comment: Claro, mis avances están en UipAth, les adjunto el link de descarga: https://www.dropbox.com/s/24sjwmg8g9hhia2/OCR_SplitTest2.zip?dl=0

Comment: Nop, todo el código deberás de colocarlo aquí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propongo una solución basada en una función *generadora*.

Una función *generadora* es una que tiene un `yield` en lugar de un `return`. El `yield` permite retornar una valor como una función normal, pero sin perder el estado. En otras palabras, la función generadora sigue ejecutando después del `yield`.

Para efectos de simular el proceso de lectura físico de los documentos, defino la función *generadora* `lector_facturas()`, que entregará facturas una a una, o sea, nunca tendré la lista completa.

```
def lector_facturas():
    facturas = ['z', 'z', 'z', 'b', 'b', 'j', 'j', 'j', 'd', 'd']
    for fac in facturas:
        yield fac
```

Para realizar lo pedido defino `agrupar()`, otra función generadora . En cada llamada me retornara el siguiente grupo de elementos (`['z', 'z', 'z'], ['b', 'b']`, etc.

```
def agrupar():
    facs = []
    for fac in lector_facturas():
        if facs and fac != facs[0]:
            yield facs
            facs = [fac]
        else:
            facs.append(fac)
    yield facs
```

Que implementa el método sugerido por el OP: ir comparando cada nuevo elemento con los anteriores y hacer el corte en cada diferencia.

Sólo nos queda usar este generador para obtener los grupos:

```
for grupo in agrupar():
    print(grupo)
```

#### Demo

```
def lector_facturas():
    facturas = ['z', 'z', 'z', 'b', 'b', 'j', 'j', 'j', 'd', 'd']
    for fac in facturas:
        yield fac

def agrupar():
    facs = []
    for fac in lector_facturas():
        if facs and fac != facs[0]:
            yield facs
            facs = [fac]
        else:
            facs.append(fac)
    yield facs


for grupo in agrupar():
    print(grupo)
```

produce:

```
['z', 'z', 'z']
['b', 'b']
['j', 'j', 'j']
['d', 'd']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me ayudo mucho tu solución